# Object conversion from InputStream - Spring integration

Tags: java, tcp, deserialization, spring-integration, tcpserver

I am trying to send object over TCP thanks to serialization in client-server application. TCP client is written on android system and I use ObjectOutputStream to send an object. TCP server is written with spring integration and I try to read this object using deserializer. Something like this:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="hosServer"
    serializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
    deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize" ..... >
```

In class which implements Serializer and Deserializer interfaces I am createing ObjectInputStream from InputSream which is the argument in deserializer method. Its working fine to the moment where I try to connect one more time to the server. Then I receive EOFException during reading object form ObjectInputStream by readObject() method.

```
public class CommandConverter implements Serializer<Command>, Deserializer<Command>{

    private ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    private CommandBuilder commandBuilder = new CommandBuilder();

    public Command deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        if (ois == null)
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        Command cmd = null;
        try {
            cmd = (Command) ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            commandBuilder.setCommandBuilder(new ImproperCommandBuilder());
            commandBuilder.createCommand();
            cmd = commandBuilder.getCommand();
        } catch (InvalidClassException e) {
            commandBuilder.setCommandBuilder(new ImproperCommandBuilder());
            commandBuilder.createCommand();
            cmd = commandBuilder.getCommand();
        }
        return cmd;
    }
```

What is the best way to get object sending over TCP in spring integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Serializer` and `Deserializer` implementations must be thread-safe. The simplest way to reach that is to make the implementation **stateless**.

Since you have those properties in your class, they become shared between different calls. And having such a state it makes the behavior unpredictable.

The `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` are not designed for sharing state.

So, you have to create `ObjectInputStream` all the time the `deserialize()` is called:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
```

and so on.